# Deprecation on a service: Symfony asks to change service name

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-4.3

I am currently trying for the first time to migrate from Symfony 3.4 to 4.3.

I'm at the stage where I have to remove the depreciation so that I can update the dependencies via composing as the [doc says](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html#upgrade-major-symfony-deprecations)

I have solved all the deprecations except one that I have a little trouble. Here it is:

> Relying on service auto-registration for type "AppBundle\Entity\AdaImporterDoc" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Create a service named "AppBundle\Entity\AdaImporterDoc" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a rare situation when upgrading to Symfony 4.

To avoid that deprecation warning message that is, in fact, a false positive ([Read This](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25265)), you can replicate the way Symfony 4 works, doing the following in your `app/config/config.yml`:

```
parameters:
    container.autowiring.strict_mode: true
```

This way that 'fake' warning message will disappear and you will get real errors, if found.

If you want to know what changed on autowiring, this [Strict Autowiring Mode](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-upgrade/service-deprecations#strict-autowiring-mode) is good place to start.

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason. I'm trying to upgrade a Symfony 3.4 app to 4 and going through deprecation warnings... our Sonata config file also contains a a bunch services definition trying to pass in Entity class paths to bubble up to AbstractAdmin, and I get the warning... I'm seeing zero solution for this yet. Symfony/Sonata's documentation doesn't even mention autowiring Entities, and I don't want to make them services, and I'm not seeing how to pass them. It's super-weird.